# How to create objects from classes in a directory using typescript

Tags: typescript, oop

Let's say I have a directory like the following

```
Shapes/
  Square.ts
  Circle.ts
  Rectangle.ts
```

my goal is to have a `Map` or an `object` that has the name of the file without the extension as the key, and the class itself within the file as the value that I can initialize using the `new` keyword.

Ex:

```js
import Application from './Application' // Supposedly my application entry point

let instances: Map<string, Shape> = Application.getShapes() // I expect that `getShapes` to return a Map as described earlier.

let square = new instanes.get("Square") // I expect to have a Square instance
```

So I am trying to avoid using this approach and have them created dynamically.

```js
import AlnumRule from './Rules/AlnumRule'
import Rule from './Rules/Contracts/Rule'
import RequiredRule from './Rules/RequiredRule'

export default class RulesMapper {
  static map: { [index: string]: Rule } = {
    required: new RequiredRule(),
    alnum: new AlnumRule(),
  }

  static resolve(rule: string): Rule {
    return RulesMapper.map[rule]
  }
}
```

In other words, I am trying to read all files within a certain directory and store the constructible classes into an object or a Map

Comment: You have not directly asked a question. What exactly is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: "the class itself within the file as the value that I can initialize using the new keyword" so you mean key => value = class constructor right?

Comment: @jsejcksn "My goal is to have a `Map` or an `object` that has the key as a string and the value is the constructor itself"
That's what I am trying to achieve but in a dynamic way, like creating a function that accepts a directory name and returns a whole object as described.
In other words, construct any constructible that's in supported directory

Comment: @RamblinRose Yea, but without constructing it myself as I provided in the second code example.

I wanna have it in some fashion that I have a function that takes a directory path and scans all files within it and construct the classes that exist within it, and for the sake of simplicity, I'll assume that all the files in the supplied directory are constructible.

Answer (score 0):

This example assumes that you are running in an environment that supports dynamic import (e.g., Node.js with CommonJS or ES modules). Note that using dynamic imports may introduce some complexity, and you should be cautious about potential security concerns, especially if the input to importAndInitializeClasses is not controlled.

Adjust the code according to your specific needs and environment.

```js
// Application.ts
import { readdirSync } from 'fs';
import { basename, join } from 'path';

// Utility function to dynamically import and initialize classes
async function importAndInitializeClasses<T>(directory: string, fileExtension: string): Promise<Map<string, T>> {
  const instances = new Map<string, T>();
  const files = readdirSync(directory).filter(file => file.endsWith(fileExtension));

  for (const file of files) {
    const className = basename(file, fileExtension);
    const filePath = join(directory, file);
    const module = await import(filePath);
    const classInstance = new module[className]();
    instances.set(className, classInstance);
  }

  return instances;
}

export default class Application {
  static async getShapes(): Promise<Map<string, unknown>> {
    return importAndInitializeClasses<unknown>('Shapes', '.ts');
  }
}

// Usage in another file
import Application from './Application';

async function main() {
  const instances = await Application.getShapes();
  const square = new (instances.get('Square'))(); // Instantiate Square dynamically
  // ...
}

main();
```